# fatal error: zephyr/kernel.h: No such file or directory when using adding add_executable() or add_library()

Tags: cmake, module, embedded, esp32, zephyr-rtos

Update: I could not able to build the Zephyr Project when adding these lines in add_executable() or add_library().

My Project is a standalone project which means it is placed out of zephyr root directory.

My Cmake looks like this,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.0)
set (BOARD esp32)
find_package(Zephyr REQUIRED HINTS $ENV{ZEPHYR_BASE})
project(sample)
FILE(GLOB app_sources src/*.c)
target_sources(app PRIVATE ${app_sources})
```

The above cmake is working successfully and I could able to build and flash the software.

Whereas, when I add the line add_executable() as mentioned below, it throws the error "**fatal error: zephyr/kernel.h: No such file or directory**"

In Main_CMakeLists.txt, added subdirectories

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.0)
set (BOARD esp32)
find_package(Zephyr REQUIRED HINTS $ENV{ZEPHYR_BASE})
project(sample)
FILE(GLOB app_sources src/*.c)
target_sources(app PRIVATE ${app_sources})
add_executable(appexe  ${app_sources})
```

No Changes in project file

Kindly let me know , how to proceed from here, as I new to both embedded and Zephyr.

Updated: Updated the question as per my latest analysis, initially i thought the issue is because of adding sub_directory(), later on I analyzed found this.